# How to get the value of 'index' and put it on a global variable?

Tags: javascript

How do I put the value of 'index' to a global variable?
The value of the index is showing only if its inside the forEach loop, is there a way to take it out and put it on a global variable?

```js
stars.forEach((star,index) =>{
    star.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        stars.forEach((star,idx) =>{
            if(idx < index + 1){
                star.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                star.classList.remove('active');
            }
            console.log(index); // this is working
        });
    });    
});
console.log(index); // this is NOT working
```

Please check thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The value of the index changes on each iteration.

Comment: Declare the variable globally and then assign the index to it

Comment: Polluting the global scope may be quite a bad idea. If you really need it (think about that twice), you have to declar a global variable and then assign it.

Comment: All you're doing in that loop is adding click listeners to some elements. _Those functions only get called when they're triggered_. So clearly _index_ will be undefined when you log it immediately after the loop because you've not clicked on anything yet.

Comment: If you only want the number of items in the stars array, then surely "console.log(stars.length);" would suffice or possible console.log(stars.length - 1);

Comment: @Andy I get what you mean, This is a 5 star rating app, the 'index' shows which star is clicked ex. I clicked 3rd star so the index is 2, I wanted to take that value '2' out and put it in a global variable so that I can use it on my switch statement later when I click the submit rating button.

switch (index value here) {
  case 0: ""
    break;
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
    break;
  case 3:
    break;
  case 4:
    break;

}

Comment: That's fine. Your submit should have its own handler. You can call that (when a button is clicked) and that can have access to your updated variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this doesn't seems to be a good idea to do but here you go:

```
var globalIdx = -1

function fnc() {
  var functionIdx = -1
  stars.forEach((star,index) =>{
    star.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        stars.forEach((star,idx) =>{
            if(idx < index + 1){
                star.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                star.classList.remove('active');
            }
            console.log(index); // this is working
            globalIdx = index;
            functionIdx = index;
        });
    });    
  });
  console.log(index); // will not work
  console.log(globalIdx); // will work
  console.log(functionIdx); // will work
}
console.log(globalIdx); // will work
console.log(functionIdx); // will not work
```

Just pick one between functionIdx and globalIdx based on what you need.

Hope this helps :)